# Export all post from database to JSON only when the database gets updated

Tags: php, json, export

I'm trying to export all the published post of my database to a JSON file, in order to use it in JS.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Export to JSON
Description: Creates the JSON file that stores all the necessary post data that are
used in the timeline js
*/

function export_posts_in_json (){

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $posts = array();

    while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    // Add a car entry
    $posts[] = array(
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'excerpt' => get_the_excerpt(),
        'author' => get_the_author()
    );

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();

    return json_encode($posts);
}

$folder = 'wp-content/themes/bootstrap/library/';
$file_name = date('Y-m-d') . '.json';
file_put_contents($folder.$file_name, export_posts_in_json());

add_action( 'save_post', 'export_posts_in_json' );
```

The code works when it is inside functions.php but it gets executed in every reload and not when the save_post hook gets triggered.
I've made it as a plugin but there is a problem in the while loop and crashes the whole site.

Any ideas?

Edit:
After mmm's suggestion, here is the final working code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Export to JSON
Author: Achilleas X.
Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/90258/
Description: Every time you save,update or delete a post, all the published post are getting saved in a JSON file in the uploads directory. Have in mind that by default it only exports "title - excerpt - author" , but you can add whatever else you want.
*/

function export_posts_in_json (){

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $posts = array();

    while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    $posts[] = array(
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'excerpt' => get_the_excerpt(),
        'author' => get_the_author()
    );

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();

    $data = json_encode($posts);
    $upload_dir = wp_get_upload_dir();
    $file_name = date('Y-m-d') . '.json';
    $save_path = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $file_name;

    $f = fopen( $save_path , "w" ); //if json file doesn't gets saved, comment this and uncomment the one below
    //$f = @fopen( $save_path , "w" ) or die(print_r(error_get_last(),true)); //if json file doesn't gets saved, uncomment this to check for errors
    fwrite($f , $data);
    fclose($f);

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'export_posts_in_json' );
```

Comment: I suggest to use [`WP File System API`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API) instead of using `file_put_contents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `file_put_contents` which saves the data then it have to be in the hook and not in the body of the plugin :

```
function export_posts_in_json () {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ...

    $data = json_encode($posts);

    $folder = 'wp-content/themes/bootstrap/library/';
    $file_name = date('Y-m-d') . '.json';
    file_put_contents($folder.$file_name, $data);
}


add_action( 'save_post', 'export_posts_in_json' );
```

Comment: I suggest to use `save_post_post` hook instead of `save_post` as OP is only looking for posts. Also check for whether we are on the new page or published page either using $pagenow global or using `save_post_post` third parameter `$update`

Comment: Great and usefull plugin, thanks, it helped me a lot to make a custom events calendar with ACF and Monthly.js.
Just one thing I had to fix was to add a 'return' statement after fclose($f) because I was getting a blank page after action was called.
So my final code was: `/* ... */ fwrite($f , $data); fclose($f); return;`