# Customize JSON output

Tags: database, json

I'm using code to generate JSON from the WordPress database. The code is from [Export all post from database to JSON only when the database gets updated](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232708/export-all-post-from-database-to-json-only-when-the-database-gets-updated)

```
function export_posts_in_json (){

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = array();

while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

$posts[] = array(
    'title' => get_the_title(),
    'excerpt' => get_the_excerpt(),
    'author' => get_the_author(),

    // I add additional data to export
    'category' => get_the_category()
);

endwhile;

wp_reset_query();

$data = json_encode($posts);
$upload_dir = wp_get_upload_dir();
$file_name = date('Y-m-d') . '.json';
$save_path = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $file_name;

$f = fopen( $save_path , "w" ); //if json file doesn't gets saved, comment this and uncomment the one below
//$f = @fopen( $save_path , "w" ) or die(print_r(error_get_last(),true)); //if json file doesn't gets saved, uncomment this to check for errors
fwrite($f , $data);
fclose($f);
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'export_posts_in_json' );
```

JSON output is

```
[
  {
    "title": "My Post 1",
    "excerpt": "My Post 1 excerpt",
    "author": "Admin",
    "category": [
      {
        "term_id": 53,
        "name": "My Category 1",
        "slug": "my-category-1",
        "term_group": 0,
        "term_taxonomy_id": 53,
        "taxonomy": "category",
        "description": "",
        "parent": 7,
        "count": 4,
        "filter": "raw",
        "meta": [

        ],
        "cat_ID": 53,
        "category_count": 4,
        "category_description": "",
        "cat_name": "My Category 1",
        "category_nicename": "my-category-1",
        "category_parent": 7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "My Post 2",
    "excerpt": "My Post 2 excerpt",
    "author": "Admin",
    "category": [
      {
        "term_id": 28,
        "name": "My Category 2",
        "slug": "my-category-2",
        "term_group": 0,
        "term_taxonomy_id": 28,
        "taxonomy": "category",
        "description": "",
        "parent": 7,
        "count": 5,
        "filter": "raw",
        "meta": [

        ],
        "cat_ID": 28,
        "category_count": 5,
        "category_description": "",
        "cat_name": "My Category 2",
        "category_nicename": "my-category-2",
        "category_parent": 7
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

my goal is to generate JSON output look like this

```
{
    "Categories": 
        [
            {
                "name": "My Category 1"
            },
            {
                "name": "My Category 2"
            },
        ],

    "Posts":
        [
            {
                "title": "My Post 1",
                "excerpt": "My Post 1 excerpt",
                "author": "Admin",
                "category": "My Category 1"
            },
            {
                "title": "My Post 2",
                "excerpt": "My Post 2 excerpt",
                "author": "Admin",
                "category": "My Category 2"
            }
        ]
}
```

Update: using motivast's code, i'm almost achieve what i'm expecting by removing `$categories = array_unique($categories);`

the JSON output look like this

```
{
    "Categories": 
        [
            {
                "name": "My Category 1"
            },
            {
                "name": "My Category 2"
            },
            {
                "name": "My Category 2"
            },
        ],

    "Posts":
        [
            {
                "title": "My Post 1",
                "excerpt": "My Post 1 excerpt",
                "author": "Admin",
                "category": "My Category 1"
            },
            {
                "title": "My Post 2",
                "excerpt": "My Post 2 excerpt",
                "author": "Admin",
                "category": "My Category 2"
            },
            {
                "title": "My Post 3",
                "excerpt": "My Post 3 excerpt",
                "author": "Admin",
                "category": "My Category 2"
            }
        ]
}
```

One step closer to my goal, removing duplicate content in Categories.

Update 2: Following Tom J Nowell's suggestion, Now i'm able to get what I want using REST API post endpoints. Of course, Motivast's code help me so much to rearranging the data structure.

Thank you Tom.

Thank you very much Motivast.

Comment: Looking at your original question, did you ever consider using the REST API post endpoints? Also, what is the problem that rearranging the data structure solves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do the job:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' =>  -1,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $posts = array();
    $categories = array();
    $json = array();

    while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        $post_categories = get_the_category();

        $post_category = current($post_categories);

        $categories[] = array(
            'name' => $post_category->name
        );

        $posts[] = array(
            'title' => get_the_title(),
            'excerpt' => get_the_excerpt(),
            'author' => get_the_author(),

            // I add additional data to export
            'category' => $post_category->name
        );

    endwhile;

    $categories = array_unique($categories);

    $json['Categories'] = $categories;
    $json['Posts'] = $posts;

    $data = json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it almost solve the problem. Your code didn't generate all available categories, it only generate one category in the Categories array,

Comment: How would you like to display multiple categories in post: `"category": "My Category 1"`? From your description and example output I understood that you want only one category.

Comment: If the posts array is all my blog posts, then categories array is all my blog categories. i would like to show all categories that available in my blog. so i expecting categories array is the list of whole categories in my blog.